# Can the code developed and running in Websphere application server v5.1 run in Websphere application server v6.0/6.1/7.0?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1, rational-rsa, websphere-6

Can the code developed and running in Websphere application server v5.1 run in Websphere application server v6.0/6.1/7.0 without any problems?

My scenario:
Originally, the application developed using Java 1.4 and WAS v5.1. As part of change request, we are going to do some changes in that application.
Currently, in my development environment i have RSA(Rational Software Architect) 7.5. It complaint with only WAS v6.0/6.1/7.0. So i can work with one of these WAS version.

1. Which version i can choose to work for development WAS v6.0/6.1/7.0?

But finally the developed/changed code in WAS6.0/6.1/7.5 will be deployed in WAS v5.1(PRODUCTION) only. I am worried about whether code will run properly or not.

1. Will i get any complaint problem in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most important is **not to change your compiler settings** from 1.4 to the RSA 7.5 default which I believe is 1.5.

In case you compile your source code with higher version of Java and deploy it in a Container which runs on a lower version you are going to have trouble.

Generally it is safe to run and test your legacy app on a higher WAS version but keep your eyes on the compiler settings as I mentioned.